# Get files from the directory - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to fetch some files from the local directory by using the dependency `path_provider: ^1.6.27`, but was getting an error stating as `Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getExtStorageData on channel path_provider_ex)`

The code where I'm fetching

```
 getFiles() async {

    directory = (Directory('storage/emulated/0/FolderName')).path;
    setState(() {
      file = io.Directory('$directory/${widget.folderName}').listSync();
    });

    List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();
}
```

Getting the error in the line `List<StorageInfo> storageInfo = await PathProviderEx.getStorageInfo();`

Have mentioned the permissions in the manifest file

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />


    <application
          android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"/>
```

Comment: Are you trying to use this package on flutter web application ?

Comment: No for the mobile application

Answer (score 0):

If you have just added the plugin this may help you.

[MissingPluginException](https://fluttercorner.com/flutter-error-missingpluginexception-no-implementation-found-for-method/)